# Why do tails of some lizards break so easily?

Tags: herpetology

When I was younger once I have tried to catch a ground lizard by its tail but,
unfortunately the tail got broken and the lizard ran away.

Why did the lizard's tail get broken so easily while other animals have stronger tails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a self-defense mechanism, the tail falls off during threatening situations, to which the reptile responds by excessively contracting the tail muscles. This process is known as "Autotomy", or "Self-Amputation". Other animals have got "stronger tails" simply because such self-defense mechanism hasn't been developed.
https://science.sciencemag.org/content/20/500/149.2
Check this link for more in depth information!